# XPath get XML attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm uploading and xml file using a php class I wrote. What I need is I need to check if ReadingDate exists in the xml or not.

```
<ProductCollect ReadingDate="2013-09-12T11:39:57.763">
```

I can get ProductCollect but how to access ReadingDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an attribute with XPath

```
/ProductCollect/@ReadingDate
```

Comment: But what if it was like 

<ProductCollect ReadingDate="2013-09-12T11:39:57.763" Test="asd">

And I wanted to access Test .

/ProductCollect/@Test or /ProductCollect/@ReadingDate/@Test ???

Comment: /ProductCollect/@Test

Comment: To explain why `/ProductCollect/@ReadingDate/@Test` wouldn't make sense: XPath is looking at the *hierarchy*, not the *sequence*. `Test` and `ReadingDate` are both at the same level of the hierarchy, one is not a child of the other; which order they appear in is irrelevant.